# How to be forewarned that my website may "break" due to browser update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge

My code had been broken by updates to Google Chrome, IE/Edge, etc many times.

Recently, looking into my production site, the update affected my code between 20:28 on 3/25/2016 and 11:58 on 3/26/2016 (the code listed below)

The code you see is just an example. My main question is:

How can I find out what updates and changes to browsers (let's say the main 3 or 4) are due to be released, so I can be forewarned that I may need to update my code? I can not find anywhere - I am probably not looking in the right place - what change was made.

This has happened to me maybe a half a dozen of times in the past few years, and at this point, I really can't have the website "breaking" with updates to browsers.

This is a geolocation script that worked fine for me until the past day or 2 (I have been away from my code for a couple of days so I cannot identify when) I use Google Chrome to test my site because I am familiar with the Dev tools and cross platform I have found to be the most consistent.

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                                                document.getElementById("xc").value = position.coords.latitude;
                                                document.getElementById("yc").value = position.coords.longitude;
                                                document.getElementById("loginform").submit();
                                            });
} else {
    document.getElementById("xc").value = '0';
    document.getElementById("yc").value = '0';
    document.getElementById("loginform").submit();
}
```

Again, my question isn't so much in the code as it is about finding a way to be forewarned about the need to re-visit and update it.

Comment: You could subscribe to the main browser newsletters to get access to beta/UAT releases. I wonder if hosted testing systems would be able to do this as well, e.g. BrowserStack?

Comment: Most browsers have a developer branch where you can test nightly builds

Comment: Just for info: as suggested by jib below, Chrome Canary and Firefox nightly both work with this code, as it is. The new update in Chrome only is broken. It works in Edge and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "intent to deprecate" (with quotes). I believe you're looking for [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/2LXKVWYkOus/gT-ZamfwAKsJ).

Chromium and Firefox at least have a process for changes which require posting notices like *Intent to deprecate*, *Intent to implement*, or *Intent to unship* in their developer forums.

Also, [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) and [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) give you a 4 month head start.

Comment: As I posted above, it works in Canary, and Nightly, as well as current versions of edge and Safari.  How do you suggest I proceed with just seemingly this version of Chrome acting up?

Comment: Are you on `https`? If not, then geolocation is on Chrome's http axe-list in the link FWIW. Dunno about Canary.